# Delay liquid page render until after Ajax returns data

Tags: javascript, jquery, liquid

I am using Liquid and have access to both the server and client sides. I want to get the users location once and then according to the users location render different liquid elements. So hiding div's won't work. 
I actually need to delay the rendering for maybe a half second, until the country code is returned via Ajax. Then I can take it from there. I tried this but no luck, its not delaying the page render, its just delaying the logging of my message to the console.

```
<script>
   $(window).load(function () {
      setTimeout(function(){ console.log("waiting 2 secs..");
        },2000); // set the time here
    });

  jQuery.ajax( {
    url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(location) {
      {% assign user_country = location.country_code %}
      console.log("Hey this is the country code " + location.country_code);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you use[.done()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)?

Comment: You don't need jsonp... when origin is included it will be CORS compitable

Comment: And the `type=post` have no affect on jsonp. jsonp can only be requested with a new script tag that is requested with just a GET request

Comment: I think you all missed the point of the question. My code isn't working. even with `async: false` the page renders before the ajax returns. I need to pause the rendering of the page load, until after the ajax returns.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use `jsonp` as this is not a best practice.

As Sam points out, you can use `done()`:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: '//freegeoip.net/json/',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    success: function(location) {
      {% assign user_country = location.country_code %}
      console.log("Hey this is the country code " + location.country_code);
    }
}).done(function() {
  // CODE HERE WILL ONLY RUN ONCE AJAX REQUEST IS COMPLETED
});
```